# Email link tracking generating a 404 on preview

Tags: civimail

CiviCRM 5.43.0 in Wordpress 5.8.2

When building a traditional mailing which includes hyperlinks, and enabling click tracking, we see the following behaviour:

When clicking the HTML Preview button in CiviCRM, the link works (no tracking enabled)

When sending the email to the intended recipients, the link works. This is an example of a link from a sent campaign:
https://heritagepulse.insights-alliance.com/civicrm/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mailing/url&u=91&qid=330

When using the "send test email to" function, on clicking a link, we see a 404 error. This is an example of how the link is constructed in 'send test email to' mode: https://heritagepulse.insights-alliance.com/civicrm/mailing/url/?u=92&qid=331

Is this intentional behaviour?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My wordpress base page was set to 'civicrm', changing it to 'civicrm/' seems to have fixed this